# Converting doc.x to pdf file using python3 in mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos

I'm beginner in python3 and I have a project to convert word files (doc.x) to pdf files on mac.

I saw few codes that relevant to windows but didn't succeeding adapt it to mac.

someone can help me?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far, and what concrete issues you are facing.

Comment: actually I don't know how to start it.. 
I tried few things:
1) I looked how to read file in bytes and then write a pdf file with the same bytes, but didn't know to to create a good pdf file with the same fonts, pictures, bolted and underscores chars.
2) I tried maybe to take a screen shot of the word doc and then creating it but it won't success if the file is more than 1 page.
3) I looked for built modules and libraries  and hoped that obviously I'm gonna find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `docx2pdf` python library to convert docx to pdf on macOS (or Windows). It uses Microsoft Word's APIs to directly convert to PDF creating a perfect copy. Internally, it uses JXA (Javscript for Automation, basically AppleScript in JS) in macOS and win32com in Windows.

Install:

```
pip install docx2pdf
```

Usage:

```
from docx2pdf import convert
convert("input.docx", "output.pdf")
```

Disclaimer: I wrote this tool after struggling to find a cross-platform solution for batch converting docx to pdf with zero formatting issues since it directly uses Microsoft Word. Please give the repo a star if it helps! https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf

Comment: Is there any package can convert doc to pdf?

Comment: Seems that this requires Microsoft word to be installed :(